# How to use "zero_terms_query" in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In document of esearch, they have an example:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "body": {
        "query": "to be or not to be",
        "operator": "and",
        "zero_terms_query": "all"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't know of any document to show the difference between `zero_terms_query: none` and `zero_terms_query: all`.
Pls help me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is described in [elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-zero)

If you setup an analyzer with configured stop-words filter (e.g with words "hello", "world") for a particular field in your index then this query:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": {
        "query": "hello world",
        "operator": "and",
        "zero_terms_query": "none"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

will yield no results as `"zero_terms_query": "none"` (default param) says to return nothing when the configured analyzer has removed all the
occurrences of "world" in the query.

On the contrary, `zero_terms_query: "all"` will simply return **ALL** the documents from the index (same as `"match all"` query)

Comment: I still don't understand. Can you write a full example documents